# Data not acting as global form factory to services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

below i am getting information from api. in console i got the data when i return iteminfo data not able to get in services.

this my factory code

```
factmodule.factory("OrderFactory", function() {
    var iteminfo;
    var Iteminforesource = $resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/menu");
    return {
        Iteminforesource.get(function(data) {

            iteminfo = data.message;
            console.log("this is menu " + iteminfo)
        }, function(d, s) {
            console.log("Error*** " + s)
        })
        return iteminfo;
    }

})
```

this is my service code.
in console data shows undefined

```
servctrl.service("OrderService", function(OrderFactory) {
    this.getAllInfoItem = function() {
        return OrderFactory.Iteminforesource();
        console.log(OrderFactory.Iteminforesource());
    }
})
```

please hlep me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about `promise` objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or Angular specific [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
factmodule.factory("OrderFactory", function() {
    var Iteminforesource = $resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/menu");
    return {
        // return promise object
        iteminfo:function{
        return Iteminforesource.get().$promise.then(function(data) {
            // promise will resolved with data.message
            return data.message;
        });
    }
    }

})

servctrl.service("OrderService", function(OrderFactory) {
    this.getAllInfoItem = function() {
        // this service also will return promise
        return OrderFactory.iteminfo();
    }
})

// in controllers getAllInfoItem must be used like this
orderService.getAllInfoItem().then(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response. Here Problem is there. it shows the Error orderService.getAllInfoItem().then is not a function. let me know how to work with promise,$q if you have any demo on this better for me.

Comment: Yep, it was my mistake. I've updated anwser (added `$promise` in factory). Full explanation of `$q` with example you can find here: http://www.webdeveasy.com/javascript-promises-and-angularjs-q-service/